# MySQL selecting only certain values from column without excluding rows

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, group-concat

I was wondering if there was a way to select only certain values in a column for use in a GROUP_CONCAT without excluding the non-matching columns from the SELECT.

Here's the specific scenario: for my WordPress site, I have `wp_22_posts` and `wp_22_postmeta` tables with a one-to-many relationship between the posts and the meta. I would like to group the joined results by `wp_22_posts.ID` and select a semicolon-separated list of `wp_22_postmeta.meta_key` and `wp_22_postmeta.meta_value` for each group. I only want to grab the meta key and value if the key matches "authorid" or "isbn"; *However, I do not want to exclude the rows without an "authorid" or "isbn"* - I would rather just return `null` or something like that for the non-matching rows.

Below is the query that I am currently using, but as you can see, it is pulling in *all* of the metadata:

```
SELECT posts.post_title, MAX(posts.post_date_gmt), posts.post_content, posts.guid AS url, posts.comment_count,
    GROUP_CONCAT(postmeta.meta_key ORDER BY postmeta.meta_value DESC SEPARATOR ';') AS meta_key,
    GROUP_CONCAT(postmeta.meta_value ORDER BY postmeta.meta_value DESC SEPARATOR ';') AS meta_value
FROM wp_22_posts AS posts
JOIN wp_22_postmeta AS postmeta ON (posts.ID = postmeta.post_id)
WHERE posts.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY posts.ID
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can use `CASE` instead of column name in `GROUP_CONCAT` :

```
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN postmeta.meta_key='authorid' OR postmeta.meta_key='isbn'
 THEN postmeta.meta_key END, .....
```

Sorry, I cannot test it at the moment, but it should work

Comment: +1, damn, you were faster. Wanted to write the same. And I also can't test it right now :)

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks for helping out this SQL amateur!